# How can I prevent my reddit bot from commenting on a post it's already commented on?

Tags: python, praw

I have a reddit bot that routinely browses the rising posts and comments on certain posts. What I'm noticing is that sometimes, my bot is commenting on the same post 3-4 times. What I have done to fix this is saving each post that I comment on, and then checking that the post is not in my saved list before commenting. That is not working - I've tried the same thing with a list, and that wasn't working either. Any ideas?

Here is my current code:

```
def search(post):
   saved = reddit.user.me().saved(limit=None)
   if post not in saved:
      ##do code here

def loopRisingPosts():
   for post in reddit.subreddit("subreddit").rising(limit=10):
       search(post)

while True:
   loopRisingPosts()
   sleep(500)
```

Any idea why this bot is commenting on the same post more than once? Often 2-3 times?

Comment: are you able to print the contents of saved to make sure they are being appended?

Comment: Yep, everything looks good and as expected. This is confusing. The thing is it works 80% of the time, but sometimes it doesnt..

Answer (score 0):

if you are going to save all of the posts that you have commented on then you can check whether you saved it or not by doing:

```
def search(post):
   if not post.saved: # each post tags if it was saved or not
      ##do code here
```

Otherwise if you aren't saving a post a different method would be to search the comments of the post for comments where your username is the author.